# Determining the number of matches to a "Find" on a given range

Tags: excel, vba, find, match

I have a macro which selects a particular range and then will find the number "0" on it.
 I would like to know how many times "0" appears in the range I've selected so that I can create a variable equal to that number. How can I set a variable equal to the number of times find returns a match for the query?

```
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
item = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("Lights").Select
Rows(3).Select
Selection.Find(What:=item, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Select
     q = ActiveCell.row()
     z = ActiveCell.Column()
    Range(Cells(q, z), Cells(72, z)).Select
    Selection.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

So if there are 7 instance of 0 on the range then I want to set variable m= 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, 0)
```

or for partial matches:

```
m = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, "*0*")
```